# Visual Basic Connect to Access DataBase

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm new to access database, and the following code shows the general process I learned in class to connect visual basic to access database and display data on form.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SalesDataConnection As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0;data source=AccessClassActivity.accdb")
        Dim SalesDataSet As New DataSet()

        Dim SalesDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from customers", SalesDataConnection)
        'SalesDataConnection.Open()

        SalesDataAdapter.Fill(SalesDataSet)
        SalesDataGridView.DataSource = SalesDataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView() ' defaultView is the datasheet view

        SalesDataConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I have a access file named *AccessClassActivity*. I have a main form named *form1*, a button named *button1*, and a datagridview named *SalesDataGridView*. 
I comment out *SalesDataConnection.Open()* on purpose to see what happens, but nothing happens and everything works well. I'm just wondering why data can be shown without opening data connection to database. Do we really need this method?

Comment: Is this VB.NET - not Access VBA? -Update your tags - and add ms-access - version if you know it

Comment: I presume that when you set up your datagridview you specified the data source as being your local Access database. Thus, you have already linked your components together and there is no need for the "Open". It is good practise to use "Open".